# MaxOccurs, invalid content and more- schemas

Tags: xml, schema

Ok initial queries are fixed, but I've still some bits that I'm confused on.

Here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='schema.xsd'>
    <book category="COOKING">
      <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
      <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
      <year>2005</year>
      <price>30.00</price>
      <photo>http://puu.sh/gNzTB/258d022e33.jpg</photo>
    </book>

    <book category="CHILDREN">
      <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
      <author>J K. Rowling</author>
      <year>2005</year>
      <price>29.99</price>
      <photo>http://puu.sh/gNzV9/e27dfc1b55.jpg</photo>
    </book>

    <book category="WEB">
      <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
      <author>James McGovern</author>
      <author>Per Bothner</author>
      <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
      <author>James Linn</author>
      <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
      <year>2003</year>
      <price>49.99</price>
    </book>

    <book category="WEB">
      <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
      <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
      <year>2003</year>
      <price>39.95</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

Heres the schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
<!-- define elements (elements with attributes or other elemens inside are complex) -->
    <xsd:element name='author' type='xsd:string' />
    <xsd:element name='year' type='xsd:gYear' />
    <xsd:element name='price' type='xsd:decimal' />
    <xsd:element name='photo' type='xsd:anyURI' />

<!-- define attributes -->
    <xsd:attribute name='category' type='xsd:string'/>
    <xsd:attribute name='lang' type='xsd:string'/>

<!-- structure -->
    <xsd:element name='title'>
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:simpleContent>
                <xsd:extension base='xsd:string'>
                    <xsd:attribute ref='lang'/>
                </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:simpleContent>
        </xsd:complexType>  
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name='book'>
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref='title'/>
                <xsd:element ref='author' maxOccurs='10'/>
                <xsd:element ref='year'/>
                <xsd:element ref='price'/>
                <xsd:element ref='photo' minOccurs='0'/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute ref='category'/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name='bookstore'>
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref='book' maxOccurs='unbounded'/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

1. When I initially tried to add such parameters(?) as min/max occurs on the initial definitions, I was rebuffed with errors. But when I added them to the ref instances of the same elements, the changes were accepted. Why is this? It seems to me that such parameters should hold position in the initial definition?

For clarification I mean I got errors with:

```
<xsd:element name='author' type='xsd:string' maxOccurs='10'/>
```

But not with:

```
<xsd:element ref='author' maxOccurs='10'/>
```

2. With the structure, mainly the title element with the attribute 'lang' I got errors with type string not being allowed as it was supposedly stated twice, once in the initial xsd:string spot, and again in complexType. Now I found a fix involving simpleContent and extensions but I'm not really sure HOW that fixed it. Any ideas?

Thank-you!

Comment: If you have performed some corrections in your schema, post it and explain what issues remains. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you focus on a single question. At the moment the questions are changing too fast to make it sensible to attempt an answer.

Comment: Ok I revisited the whole post, should be a bit clearer now.